# What's grammar for a^n b^n c^n d^n

Tags: turing-machines, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

What wiil be grammar rules for the language L={a^n b^n c^n d^n; n>0}

Answer (score 1):

May I propose the following [indexed grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_grammar) $G= ( \{S,A,C\}, \{a,b,c,d\}, \{f\}, S )$:

- $S[\sigma] \to S[f\sigma]$
- $S[\sigma] \to A[\sigma]\, C[\sigma]$
- $A[f\sigma] \to a\, A[\sigma]\, b$, $\quad A[\,] \to \varepsilon$
- $C[f\sigma] \to c\, C[\sigma]\, d$, $\quad C[\,] \to \varepsilon$

Comment: How can I turn it into Context sensitive grammar?

Comment: Writing a context-sensitive grammar better be done directly. The method might be borrowed from the grammar for [$\{ ww \mid w\in \{a,b\}^* \}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13345/4287). I quote: "try to think of using a [grammar for $a^nb^n$] twice, one for the left and one for the right half. All you have to ensure that both grammars derive 'in sync'. This can be done by swapping around a control token."